# 8250 serial driver on Guest(DOMU) Vs 8250 serial driver on Host(DOM0)

Tags: linux, hypervisor

I am working with hypervisor. In this i have DOM0 os which is using ttyS0 on 
8250 serial driver.

On this OS, i am running a device manager application which starts the DOMU kernel, which 
is using ttyS0 and ttyS1 on 8250 serial driver.

Here on the guest logs i am able to see the "printf of device manger 
application running on DOM0" and DOMU logs.

I assumed 8250 serial driver on guest(DOMU) is pass through in that case 
what about the DOM0 8250 serial driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assumed 8250 serial driver on guest(DOMU) is pass through

It isn't. The "8250" visible to the guest is a virtual device which will typically output to a socket or log file.

You are probably mistaken about seeing messages from the host in the guest's log files.

Comment: What is the role of pci_stub over here

Comment: None. The 8250 isn't a PCI device.